# Questions about cosets etc.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand my notes that my teacher gave me, so... please answer those questions in bold.

From my teacher's notes: "Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. For any $a\in G$, we define its associated left coset and right coset to be $$aH = \{ab | b \in H\}$$ $$Ha = \{ba | b\in H\}$$ respectively."

**What is a coset?

What are the differences between left and right?**

.

Also from the notes: "Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. The left cosets $\{aH | a\in G\}$ define a partition of $G$, so are the right cosets."

**What does "define a partition of $G$" mean?**

.

Also: "A function $f:G\rightarrow H$ where $G$, $H$ are groups is called a group homomorphism if $$f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$$ for all $a,b \in G$. It's called an isomorphism if it's bijective."

**Can anyone explain the notation of "$f:G\rightarrow H$"?

What does bijective mean?**

Comment: Why did you [ask this question twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487075/difference-between-left-and-right-cosets)?

Comment: still didnt understand, so i posted again with more questions

Comment: Then it would have been better if you had edited your original post to expand your questions rather than pussy basically the same question again not an hour later. Also, I still stand by my comment on that post. Try a few examples. The only way to get any intuition on definitions you don't understand is to see them in action. Apply them to the group of integers or some other similar group that you already know well, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of left / right coset are right there, and the different definitions make it clear that left and right coset are in general different.

A partition of a set $X$ is a collection of (non-empty) subsets of $X$ such that these subsets are pairwise disjoint while the union of all these subsets is $X$.

If $X,Y$ are sets, the notation $f\colon X\to Y$ expresses that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$; that is, for each $x\in X$, $f$ defines some $f(x)\in Y$.
A function can be *injective* (or *one-to-one*) meaning that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ holds only when $x_1=x_2$; it can be *surjective* (or *onto*) if for every $y\in Y$ there is at least one $x\in X$ with $f(x)=y$; and if a function is both injective and surjective, it is called *bijective*.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, Wikipedia is a good enough source to read & understand these basic concepts in Algebra.

(Cosets) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset

(Partitions of a group) https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Left_cosets_partition_a_group

(Group Isomorphism)https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism